# Android studio Flutter hot reload button is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, hot-reload

In android studio my hot reload and hot restart buttons are always inactive.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/liqEv.jpg

Android studio version:3.4
android studio sdk tools version:26.1.1
flutter doctor no issues

Comment: Are your application running on connected device? Did you run app with Android Studio? Do you have internet access?

Comment: no its running on an emulator

Comment: how to i flutter run with r?

Answer (score 0):

See at Android studio's top Right side. You can reload and hot restart from there otherwise open run from bottom there is also given both button.

Comment: the button is still inactive

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this response ,might still be relevant or helpful to anyone out there, but the solution is to make sure nothing is using the port on your terminal,
For example if you have like a we project already running in vscode, stop it, then restart your android studio app.
If no other project is running , then you might have to kill all background processes on your terminal.

Other checks involves

1. Verify that your device is still connected.
2. Verify that your device is active.

Hope this helps.